# Finding a string in a txt of house addresses with number ranges by passing in exact number and street names

Tags: bash, grep, scripting, find, regular-expression

### Context

I'm a postal worker (mail sorter) and am trying to write a bash script which allows me to input an exact street address and first couple letters of a street name, and have it return the matched string which contains the route number information. I have to sort thousands of letters which can't be machined per day by looking down at the letter, then looking up at massive posters with every address in my city on them. This script could save me literal hours, so I'm trying my hardest to learn the process to get it done. I have a hobby-like background in unix/linux scripting. Not sure if regex is the solution here, or variations of grep, find, awk, sed, or all of them!

I have a text file with a list of addresses (house number ranges and street names), each on newlines, like such:

```
6974-7075 hwy 99: ss1
7757-8079 hwy 99: ss14
98-258 even foo st N: 15
97-257 odd foo st N: 16
21-301 foo st S: 17
15-20 foo st S: 7
bar st: 1
fake st: 31
fake pl: 77
sample dr: 89
```

Notice the existance of number ranges, streets with one route (no house #'s given), even and odd specifiers, road type (st, hwy, pl, dr, etc.), north(N) and south(S) indicators, and finally route info after a colon.

### Current State

I have the following script that can return the strings I want as long as I input a street number which appears exactly as is in the text file:

```
#! /bin/bash

civic="$1"
street="$2"

grep $civic.*$street /path/to/addresses.txt
```

executing `./script.sh 7757` or `./script.sh 7757 h` will return `7757-8079 hwy 99: ss14` for me. I like the full string returned here, not just the route after the colon. But, obviously, executing `./script.sh 8020 h` won't return `7757-8079 hwy 99: ss14`, as my code doesn't check for numbers within a range yet.

### Help Needed

However, I'm looking for a way to be able to enter `8020 h` and still have it return `7757-8079 hwy 9: ss14`, as 8020 is within the range 7757-8079.

Furthermore, notice foo st in the text has an even and odd range with different routes, as well as N and S indicators. I'm looking for a way to be able to enter `107 f` or `107 foo` and have it return `97-257 odd foo st N: 16`, without also returning `98-258 even foo st N: 15`, as the house # is odd. The words even/odd will always be specified in the strings for those even/odd cases, so maybe a grep or search for those words in a string with a number range if the house # entered is odd? That example would also return `21-301 odd foo st S: 17` (notice foo st S) as the the house # is within the range, and the string has odd in it. I'm ok with this returning both N and S, as I won't have time to specify N or S.

I'd be extremely grateful for any help offered in my endeavor, whether a fully fleshed out answer, or a hint at getting closer. Not here to mooch, but simply ask for some help! Let me know if I can be more specific.

Comment: There is a lot of questions in your question. I think the first step is to format your addresses.txt file like for exemple a csv file to get always the same number of fields. Good luck.

Comment: @ctac_ I thought about that, but some of the address strings have varying amounts of fields with additional info which I need to see. I guess if it's formatted to CSV awk/sed etc would be able to specifically search the first & second fields (house # & street) to return the whole string, makes sense. I'll work on reformatting the txt to CSV with house #, odd/even, street, road type, N/S, then route info fields.

Comment: Just some notes from years of writing programs... Clearly define your main objective as the first step. If it is not clearly defined, then you will encounter lots of problems as you break it down in to smaller sub-tasks... Which is what you do next. Refine the problem repeatedly to break it down in to smaller sub-tasks until each sub-task is simple and manageable. For example, finding something within a range: Check first if it is greater than the lower range boundary. If it is, then check if it is less than the upper range boundary. Process of elimination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bsh
#! /bin/bash

civic="$1"
street="$2"

if [ "$((civic%2))" = 1 ]; then
   exclude=" even "
else
   exclude=" odd "
fi

</path/to/addresses.txt grep "$street" \
   | grep -v "$exclude" \
   | awk -F '[ -]' -v civic="$civic" '
      {if ($1 !~ /^[0123456789]*$/ || $2 !~ /^[0123456789]*$/) print
       else if (civic>=$1 && civic<=$2) print}
     '
```

The procedure:

1. Check if the number is odd or even and prepare an exclusion string accordingly.
2. The first `grep` selects lines that match the street. All lines match an empty string, so not specifying a street will make all lines match in this step.
3. The second `grep` excludes entries described as "odd" or "even", using the exclusion string from the step one.
4. `awk` splits each line, taking spaces and `-` as delimiters. If any of the two first fields is not entirely numerical, there is no range specified and the line is printed. Otherwise apparently the two first fields define a range; the number is then tested against the range and the line printed if within the range.

Comment: Amazing, works how I need. Furthermore, how would I make it so grep only looks for streets that begin with the street letters I put in? For example `20 test` returns both `10-30 test rd: 1` and `10-30 fastest st: 88`. I imagine making it so the `grep "$street"` line doesn't catch anything before `$street` (so it only looks for matches that start with the letters I pass in for street), but can catch anything after `$street` so I can still put in `20 tes` and it'll give me `10-30 test rd: 1` without `10-30 fastest st: 88`, or `10-50 latest cres: 22`. Maybe an asterisk or a grep option?

Comment: This seems to work: `</path/to/addresses.txt grep [^a-z]tes.*`, but I can't get it to work with the variable in the script, returns a blank. EDIT: Nevermind was quoting it wrong: `</path/to/addresses.txt grep "[^a-z]${street}.*"`. Notice anything there that might throw exceptions in some cases?

Comment: Ok, turns out the `[^a-z]` addition excludes the ability to find addresses without house #s. Any suggestions? I think using `\b` instead of `[^a-z]` solved it. Thoughts?

Comment: @YMGenesis `grep -E "(^| )$street"` instead of `grep "$street"`.

Comment: ok one more thing I noticed. Not sure if I should be asking it here, or adding it to my original question. There are some string lines in the text that have single house #s + street name, AND house # ranges. ex: `1 fake st: 1` newline `2-20 fake st: 99` newline `21-99 fake st: 42` newline `100 fake st: 33`. If I input `15 fak` it will return the expected `2-20 fake st: 99`, along with all the non-ranged house #s like `1 fake st: 1`, `100 fake st: 33`, resulting in 3 matching strings, where I only want `2-20 fake st: 99`. Any idea on how I can have it disregard the non-ranged matches? Thanks!

Comment: @YMGenesis Single numbers were not in the example you posted. Can you rewrite `1 fake st: 1` to `1-1 fake st: 1` etc.? Or will it be too much work? I think I can change my `awk` code to seek for the first not-entirely-numerical field and therefore know if there's a range, a single value or nothing before the street name. But then what will stop you from requesting support for `N` and `S`? Substantially changing a question after an answer appeared is not in the gist of the site. Neither is asking in comments. Please don't make it a [chameleon question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478).

Comment: @YMGenesis (cont'd) Asking a new question is in the gist. You can admit it's a follow-up question. You can link to the current question to provide context but please make the new question standalone: explain anew with more complete example, post the code you already have. If it's the code from my or the other answer then a citation would be proper, I think. Show your research effort where it comes to the new problem.

Comment: Thanks for the info (it says I'm not supposed to thank people in comments/questions, but I do appreciate the info). I do see that I left out single house numbers in my original question. I guess my lack of knowledge on the subject didn't foresee the issue because there are many facets to the problem (in my eyes). I see your `1-1 fake st: 1` solution, however it'd probably take me days to repurpose the single house numbers in my text file (too many addresses). `N` `S` don't mean anything to me as I won't have time to search for `1 fake st n`. I can create a similar question citing your work.

Comment: @YMGenesis Maybe I will help you under the new question. FYI: if my answer was the only one, I wouldn't mind adjusting it to new requirements. But the other answer is roughly as good as mine in solving the original problem and if you change the question and if I adjust my answer then the other answer will become partial, despite the author's effort to make it complete at the time they answered. It would be unfair. Let's not do this.

Comment: I completely understand. I will post a new question when I have time using the details you provided from the gist (follow-up question, new context, more complete example, posting and citing your code). I will think about how it currently performs and if there's anything more I'd like to ask, then research it myself. If I can't solve it using the hints you gave about awk looking for range, single value, or nothing, I will post a new question and be sure to cite you in it. Really, the single house #s is the only thing I need to research and try to achieve at this point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124045/discussion-between-ymgenesis-and-kamil-maciorowski).

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` and a `bash` wrapper. Save it as `script.sh` and make it executable.

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="data.txt"

n="$1"       # save number from argument list
shift        # remove number from argument list
s="$@"       # save remaining argument list
s="${s:=.*}" # set regex .* as default if street is missing

awk -v number="$n" -v street="$s" '
BEGIN{
  FS="-| "   # use field separator "-" or one space to split current row
}

$0 ~ street{
  # current row contains street

  if( $1 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ && $2 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ ){
    # current row starts with a range

    if( number >= $1 && number <= $2 ){
      # number is in expected range

      if ( $3 == "odd" || $3 == "even" ){
        # string "even" or "odd" found

        if ( $3 == "odd" && number ~ /[13579]$/ ){
          # odd
          print
        }

        if ( $3 == "even" && number ~ /[24680]$/ ){
          # even
          print
        }
      } else {
        # neither "even" or "odd" found
        print
      }
    }
    # finished with current row
    next
  }
  # match but no range found in current row
  print
}
' "$filename"
```